# Access session params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a multistep form where i save some values in the session model.

```
params[:event][:start] = DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:start], "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %P")  - offset.hours

session[:event_params].deep_merge!(params[:event]) if params[:event]
```

And I would like to access these variable later on, how should I do please?
I tried `session[:event_params][:start]` but it returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

I ended using the following:

```
params[:event][:start] = session[:event_params].values[5] + offset.hours
```